# Subscribing to an event in a different module in Prism

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism

In My `LoginModule` in an a view model I'm dispatching an event:

```
void LoginUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _eventAggregator.GetEvent<LoginStatusEvent>().Publish(_status);
}
```

In the `EventModule`:

```
public class LoginStatusEvent : PubSubEvent<LoginStatus>
{
}
```

Then I'm trying to subscribe to it in a different module:

```
public class EventModule : IModule
{
    IRegionManager _regionManager;
    IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private SubscriptionToken subscriptionToken;
    private bool isLoggedIn { get; set; }

    public EventModule(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        LoginEventsListener();
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {

    }

    public void LoginEventsListener()
    {
        LoginStatusEvent loginStatusEvent = _eventAggregator.GetEvent<LoginStatusEvent>();

        if (subscriptionToken != null)
        {
            loginStatusEvent.Unsubscribe(subscriptionToken);
        }

        subscriptionToken = loginStatusEvent.Subscribe(LoginStatusEventHandler, ThreadOption.UIThread, false);
    }

    public void LoginStatusEventHandler(LoginStatus loginStatus)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(">> Got it!!");

    }

}
```

However the `LoginStatusEventHandler` is never fired and I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: Where do you define the event? Both publisher and subscriber need to reference the exact same type.

Comment: The event is defined in the `EventModule`, fired in the `LoginModule` and I'm trying to subscribe to it in the `EventModule` as well

Comment: Did it work with 'True' flag into 'Subscribe' method?

Comment: Yes, yes it did. Please put it in an answer @galakt and I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP didnt keep Subscriber Reference when subscribe for event, so in one moment class had no references at all and collected by GC.

So in this case it will work with `True` flag into `Subscribe` method.

As @Haukinger right noted:

In Prism documentation
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/ef1a2266905a4aa3e7087955e9f7b5a7d71972fb/Documentation/WPF/30-ModularApplicationDevelopment.md#initializing-modules

`Module instance lifetime is short-lived by default. After the Initialize method is called during the loading process, the reference to the module instance is released. If you do not establish a strong reference chain to the module instance, it will be garbage collected. This behavior may be problematic to debug if you subscribe to events that hold a weak reference to your module, because your module just "disappears" when the garbage collector runs.`

Comment: When OP said "put it as an answer and I will accept", he meant, formulate that comment into a proper answer. This is still a comment. You should why this works...

Comment: @CallumLinington You are true

Comment: You might want to mention this from prism documentation `Note: Module instance lifetime is short-lived by default. After the Initialize method is called during the loading process, the reference to the module instance is released. If you do not establish a strong reference chain to the module instance, it will be garbage collected. This behavior may be problematic to debug if you subscribe to events that hold a weak reference to your module, because your module just "disappears" when the garbage collector runs.`, as one might think that the subscription token keeps the subscription alive.